# Alternative to Captchas

Tags: jquery, captcha

Can checking for changes in pointer location identify a spam bot?

By following the below rules:

- Preventing form submission directly to the url by adding a hidden
  key input
- By limiting form submission to a specific count (say 3)
- Detecting changes in pointer location

Can spam be prevented by using the above rule as an alternative to captchas?

**Basic version of question:** does the pointer location change or is it even valid when spam bots visit?

Edit:
By detecting pointer location as well as focus on input fields.

Comment: define "pointer location"

Comment: Not everyone uses a mouse.

Comment: What if I'm browsing your website with a screen reader or with only my keyboard? Worse yet, what if I disable JavaScript? Your other two "rules" are easily bypassed.

Comment: @RGraham pointer location can be detected on touchscreens afik..

Comment: +1 for Both. I agree. Mouse is not always required

Comment: @geedubb pointer location as the co-ordinates of the pointer

Comment: @blo I know. There are so many more input options than just touch and pointers. Keyboard-only & Screen Reader as pointed out by Blender are two massively important sections of users you can't ignore.

Comment: @RGraham oh yeah, screen readers, what if I also check for input focus, like satisfying any one condition..?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot stops bots using client-side Javascript. You'll have to send some "proof" to the server, which will have to evaluate that proof and accept or reject the entire request based on it. Your "pointer location" would have to be a value you send in the request, populated via Javascript; e.g.:

```
example.com/foo?pointer_x=245&pointer_y=678
```

It's hopefully pretty obvious that this is rather pointless. You may as well embed *any* random value via Javascript in the URL to proof that the client is able to run Javascript. It's hopefully also obvious that any bot explicitly targeting your website will be able to add these two random values to their submissions as well. This is pretty much just a honey-value, that it's based on the mouse pointer is irrelevant.

So: no, it's not really an alternative to captchas.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks 'deceze', good answer.

'blo', in response to the title of the question, 'Alternative to Captcha', I recently tried this which is working very well, so far. I split the email address into parts.

```
function join_email() {
var EmailName = document.getElementById('EmailName').value;
var DomainName = document.getElementById('DomainName').value;
document.getElementById('EmailAddress').value = EmailName + '@' + DomainName;
```

}

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/SimonDarby/8yBH4/

A better version would be to reassemble the email address server-side, but that's not always possible, so this may be an alternative for you to consider.

Comment: Don't you think this can be easily noticed..like the spammer will just post directly the email in parts?